# Row Sum is 1 for invertible matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $C$ be an Invertible real matrix of order n .If each row sum of $C$ is 1, then show that row sum of $C^{-1}$ also is 1.
 Can I get some help.Thanks for your time.

Comment: What do you mean by each row is C being 1? The entries are '1' or what?

Comment: How are the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $C$ related to those of $C^{-1}$?

Comment: this would be row sum,sorry for typo

Comment: the one eigenvalue of C is 1 and corresponding eigenvector is (1,1,.....1).then one eigen value of $C^{-1}$ is also 1, and corresponding eigen vector is also same.@Daniel Fischer

Answer (score 1):

Sum of each row equals  to $1$ means $1$ is an eigenvalue of the matrix. Then we can write $Ax=1x$ where $x$ is an eigen vector. Now since $A$ is given to be invertible so $$A^{-1}Ax=A^{-1}x \implies x=A^{-1}x.$$ So $1$ is also the eigenvalue of $A^{-1}$. Can you take from here?

**Edit:** As you know $x=(1,1,\ldots,1)^t$ is an eigenvector corresponding to $1$. What will you get when you multiply $A^{-1}$ by $x$?

Comment: if a matrix has every row sum equal to 1 if and only if v ⃗ = (1, 1, ... , 1 ) is an eigenvector of A with eigenvalue 1 .(Is it TRUE?)

Comment: @Subha : Yes, it's true. I was about ready to post that.

Comment: @Subha I hope this makes everything clear to you. If not then we will happy to discuss.

Answer (score -1):

Suppose $\;C=(c_{ij})\;$ , so we're given

$$\forall i=1,2,...,n\;:\;\;\sum_{j=1}^na_{ij}=1$$

We have that if $\;C^{-1}=(d_{ij})\;$ , then $\;I=C^{-1}C=\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^nd_{ik}a_{kj}\right)\implies$

$$\implies\,\forall\,i\;,\; 1=\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^nd_{ik}a_{kj}=\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^nd_{ik}a_{kj}=\sum_{k=1}^nd_{ik}\sum_{j=1}^na_{kj}=\sum_{k=1}^nd_{ik}\cdot1=\sum_{k=1}^nd_{ik}$$

and thus the rows sum of $\;C^{-1}\;$ is also $\;1\;$ .

Comment: You cannot pull the $d_{kj}$ out of the sum over $k$. This is why I edited your solution.

Comment: @user218931 Thank you, but your intented edition was more than that and a simple comment would have sufficed as I can simply change the order of summation. The answer's still basically correct but I shall edit this little thing now.

Comment: This is still wrong. The equation $\sum_{k=1}^na_{ik}\sum_{j=1}^nd_{kj} = 1\cdot \sum_{j=1}^nd_{kj}$ does *not* hold in general. I still think you have to start with $C^{-1}C$ instead of $CC^{-1}$.

Comment: @user218931 I beg to differ: why wouldn't it suffice or why is this incorrect!? These are finite sums and everything is commutative here. Unless you can prove why is that false, or give a counter example, I'll stick with this. Observe *carefully* the indexes ! And the equation does hold because of the condition on the rows of $\;C\;$ , of course. And certainly $\;CC^{-1}=C^{-1}C\;$ , that makes no difference... *and it shouldn't*.

Comment: I did observe carefully the indices. What I noticed is that on the left side you sum over $k$ and on the right side the sum over $k$ vanishes but the $k$ still appears in the index. Please tell me how this could be possible (without showing first that $\sum_{j=1}^nd_{kj}$ is independent of $k$).

Comment: @user218931 Because the left sum is one ! You could say, if you want though I think this is completely unnecesary here, thatthe third step is true "for any $\;k\;$" . What's the problem? I can't see. I think that at this level to show that sum, **any** sum, $\;\sum\limits_k d_{kj}\;$ does *not* depend on the running index is, or should be, trivial.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39215/discussion-between-user218931-and-joanpemo).

Comment: I need to go now and I can't continue. Please do ask someone else if you want and check your maths. This is correct.

Comment: The sum $r_k = \sum_{j = 1}^n d_{kj}$ may depend on $k$. When changing the order of summation, you get $$\sum_{j = 1}^n \sum_{k = 1}^n c_{ik}d_{kj} = \sum_{k = 1}^n \Biggl(c_{ik}\sum_{j = 1}^n d_{kj}\Biggr) = \sum_{k = 1}^n c_{ik} r_k.$$ Before you know that all row sums are equal, you cannot simply pull $r_k$ out of the sum.

Comment: @DanielFischer  Thank you.Then it is the same in the inverse order as it was written before (don't know if you saw) when summing over the rows $\;a_{ik}\;$, which we already know equal one. I shall edit now.

Comment: You can't pull $d_{kj}$ out of $\sum_{k = 1}^n a_{ik}d_{kj}$ unless it doesn't depend on $k$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I honestly can't see what's the problem, but I did a new edition and this time I even adopted the suggestion by user218931 (thank you) so as things are clearer. After all, $\;CC^{-1}=C^{-1}C\;$ so either way is correct and since in one, as shown in the edition now, there's no problem of dependency on some index, also the other way should be the same. Anyway, I hope this time it is satisfying for all. I'm leaving this post on in spite of the downvote only because I think some people (say, me) can learn from it. Thank you all.

Comment: Now it's fine (except for a small notational glitch, you denoted the components of $C$ as $c_{ij}$ in the first line and used $a_{ij}$ after). The problem was that you couldn't justify the manipulations - without assuming a significant part of what was to be proved - in the one order of multiplication, while in the other order, it works. Now, when you switch the order of summation, you clearly compute the row sums of $C$. These are given as the premise, so you know they are all the same, and hence you can pull out the constant to get the row sum of $C^{-1}$ in the remaining summation.

Comment: In $C\cdot C^{-1}$, when you switch the order of summation, you get the row sums of $C^{-1}$. But before you know that all row sums of $C^{-1}$ are identical, you can't pull out the constant to see that what remains is a row sum of $C$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you, I think I can see now clearer what is your point (and most probably user's, as well): if I use $\;CC^{-1}\;$, to justify the taking out something depending on a running index I either justify there somehow or use that *in the inverse order* multiplication it is fine...but then why the heck not better write the inverse order product and mess not things up?! Thank you again.